# Update data in table which has foreign keys in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys

I have two tables where one is connected to the other with a foreign key. The model *store_table* already consists of three rows, for three different stores.

I am now trying to update the model *price_table* but I am not quite sure that I understand how to utilize the foreign keys, so that it knows which *price_table* item to be connect to which *store_table* id.

Any suggestions out there on how to achieve this?

**My two models**

```
class store_table(models.Model):
    store = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    number = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            (
                "store",
                "number",
            ),
        )

class price_table(models.Model):
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    dates = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    store_id = models.ForeignKey(
        store_table, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None
    )
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            (
                "dates",
                "price",
            ),
        )
```

**My code to update the model price_table**

```
update_models = price_table(
            dates=dates,
            price=price
        )
        update_models.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that got me confused, but I think this is what you want:

```py
# NOTE: store is the store instance you want the price to be associated with
# For example, store = store_table.objects.get(pk=...)
# And you could iterate through every store object and CREATE the price
# for that store using the code below.  Again, this does not UPDATE,
# this CREATES a new price_table object for that store_table object.

update_models = price_table(
            store_id=store
            dates=dates,
            price=price
        )
update_models.save()
```

Why am I confused?  The above code will CREATE a new price_table object, not update it.  If you had a price_table object already that you wanted to UPDATE, that is change, then it would ALREADY be associated with a store, in which case you could do this:

```py
# update_models here would be an object you FIND, not CREATE, for example,
# update_models = price_table.objects.get(pk=...)

update_models.dates = dates
update_models.price = price
update_models.save()
```

Remember, you can't update a MODEL, you update an INSTANCE of a model.  The model is just a template for creating instances or objects based on that model.  You do not update the template, you update the instance.  Now, if the INSTANCE of your price_table does NOT have a sales_table associated with it yet (you have, after all, default=None for the store_id), then you could modify the above to:

```py
# Again, here, update_models will be a price_table INSTANCE you find, and
# store would be the store_table object you find, i.e.
# store = store_table.objects.get(pk=...)
# where pk is the primary key of the store you want the price associated with

update_models.store_id = store
update_models.dates = dates
update_models.price = price
update_models.save()
```

There was something else that got me confused.  For classes you want to use Pascal case, that is, instead of store_table, write Store, instead of price_table, write Price (they are all tables, after all).

This is another point that confused me.  Price should be some kind of number, correct?  Then why have it as a CharField?  Might it not be better to use a [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) instead?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer Raphael! Sorry for the confusions, I tried to "simplify" the models when I wrote this question so some errors might be there, such as CharField instead of DecimalField etc. I will create a new object in price_table each day, so I guess create is correct. What I don't seem to understand regarding your solution store_id = store is, do I have to create a store instance as the variable store? In this case perhaps a for loop to get each id in store table, and use that as the variable store? Hope my question makes sense

Comment: If I do that, I get "ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "price_table.store_id" must be a "store_table" instance."

Comment: Your answer does make sense.  Apologies.  There is an error in my answer, it should be `store = store_table.objects.get(pk=...)`.  I changed it, @barruntlek.  Yes, if you want to create new price_table objects each day for each store, then yes, my first code is what should work, with the change I made.  The error, "ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "price_table.store_id" must be a "store_table" is just saying that it's looking for a store_table object, not a number, but I think that `store_table.objects.get(pk=...)` will give you just that.